# Firebase - Updating a child value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a child value within Firebase.

This is the HTML:

```
  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider color="light">We Need</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let list of lists" (click)="unlist()">{{list?.foodname}}</ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
```

Arrays were declared in the TS here:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  foods;
  lists;
  startAt = new Subject()
  endAt = new Subject()
```

The function in the TS is:

```
  unlist() {
    firebase.database().ref('/foods').child('state')
            .update({ state: "unlisted" });
  }
```

This is my database

[image]

Right now, firing this function adds the child of "state" to "foods" rather than changing the pre-existing state. What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  Here is the simple method */
unlist() {
    from(foods).pipe(map(food => f.key), tap(key => {
        firebase.database().ref('/foods' + key).child('state')
            .update({
                state: "unlisted"
            });
    })).subscribe(val => {
        console.log("Finished updating")
    });
}

/* Merging updates into One subscription */
unlist() {
    merge(
        from(foods).pipe(map(food => f.key), map(key => {
            return fromPromise(firebase.database().ref('/foods' + key).child('state')
                .update({
                    state: "unlisted"
                }))
        }))
    ).subscribe(val => {
        console.log("Finished updating")
    })
}
```

I used here the Observable  library as you need to import these :

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import { tap,map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```